# Why htmlentities & html_entity_decode is not working properly by PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.
I have overridden core get method to encode data by htmlentities().

```
public function get($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL)
{
    $this->escape_html_content($_GET);
    return $this->_fetch_from_array($_GET, $index, $xss_clean);
}
private function escape_html_content(&$array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value) {
        if (is_string($value) && ! $this->is_json($value)) {
            $value = htmlentities($value);
        }
    });
}
```

So i am get data using $this->input->get('key'), and to store to database.
I don't know what client entered but it stored in database like,

```
公庵路208&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;ndash;214號
```

When i am trying to decode it by html_entity_decode() then it is not working, it is return same output as above.
I don't know where the problem is so please help to fix it.

Comment: `amp;` is no HTML entity. `&amp;` is one, and there's only one in your string, which gets properly decoded.